# Virtualenv throws an error when I try virtualenv -p python3

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenv

All of a sudden When I try to add python3 to virtualenv like this

```
virtualenv -p python3 env
```

I get the following error

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 726, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 746, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-13.1.2.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'
```

This just started happening out of nowhere a few hours ago because I have been using it tonite. Can anyone tell me what's going on with this? thanks

Comment: Have you upgrade virtualenv or anything else in the meantime?

Comment: I was trying out cookiecutter and heroku and all of a sudden this started happening. weird, anyway I upgraded like you said, and things are working. If you made this an answer I could've gave you credit. something with cookiecutter through my system off